# Is it possible to switch a repository to a subdirectory on Github?

Tags: github

I currently have some repositories for a Coursera course setup like this...

```
username\classApp
username\classApp-Ang
```

I'd like to change this to...

```
username\FullStackCoursera\classApp
username\FullStackCoursera\classApp-Ang
```

While still maintaining the current folder structure locally.  Is this possible?   I just want to have things a little more organized.  I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: What was the issue when you tried it?

Comment: Sorry - I'll revise.  I'm not sure how to

Answer (score 0):

More about moving files in git [here](https://githowto.com/moving_files)

```
mkdir username/FullStackCoursera
git mv username/classApp username/FullStackCoursera`
```

Then double check your changes with

```
git status
```

Comment: that wouldn't change things locally as well?  Locally I don't have a folder with my username.  I just want to change the structure on github